# Haskell list comprehension error

Tags: haskell

I just started to learn Haskell today and is completely overwhelmed by its syntax.

I am trying to apply math calculation to a list of items.

For example, lets say I want to square every item in the list using list comprehension.

My attempt

```
myfunc (n:lis) = [ k | k <-lis, k == k^k]

result_list = myfunc[1..]

take 10 result_list
```

My understand of my `myfunc` code: take a list and loop through elements that is stored in variable k and set k equals to its square.

after i execute the `take` command, and hit enter, apparently the process is running but does not do anything.

Note that i want to use list comprehension as a way to do it. I can use `map` do achieve my goal already.

Comment: No, this is totally wrong. You cannot "set" a variable in Haskell. `k == k^k` means "k is equal to its own kth power" (it's a boolean condition). There aren't many such numbers out there, and your function just happens to skip the first and only one, so there's no output.

Comment: @n.m. is `(n:lis)` equivalent of Java's `(for var in array)`?

Comment: If you want to generate a list of squares, you need something like `[k^2|k<-lis]`.

Comment: "is (n:lis) equivalent of Java's " no, they even weren't in the same town.

Comment: @n.m. thank you for the explination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand the list comprehension.

```
[ k | k <- lis, k == k^k ]
```

The `k == k^k` clause is a *filter* –– it only keeps elements of the list that satisfy this equation.  (`==` is a comparison operator that returns a bool, which is one hint).  The reason you see no output is that there are no numbers in `[1..]` that satisfy this equation.  But we get an infinite loop because we keep checking ever higher numbers to see if they satisfy it.

Something to experiment with

```
[ k | k <- lis, k < 100 ]
```

As for how to get a list of squares, use a comprehension like this

```
[ k^2 | k <- lis ]
```

If you want something more like your original phrasing, you can make `let` bindings within  a list comprehension:

```
[ r | k <- lis, let r = k^2 ]
```

There are other issues with your code, but one baby step at a time!  Good luck!

Comment: I dont quite understand the point of (n:lis) in this case.  In the working code here: `myFunc (n:lis) = [ k^k | k <-lis]`, N does not seem to function as anything.

Comment: @aDev `n` is the first element of the list (which your function throws away). `lis` is the tail of the list (everything but the first element). If you want to use the input list as is, use `myFunc lis = [ ... ]`.

Comment: `[ k | k <- lis, k < 100 ]`, which can be written `filter (<100) lis` has a potential problem; it will never stop checking values from `lis` to see if they happen to satisfy `<100`. If we know they grow monotonically, we can get a terminating list instead using `takeWhile (<100) lis`. In this example, we expect the `take 10` in the original code to make sure we don't see the part where the filter runs indefinitely without completing (which happened immediately for the original comprehension).